# Not able to start Apache HTTP Server on Cent OS 6.4

Tags: apache

While starting Apache tomcat, am getting error Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Invalid command 'AddHandler', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration   I am using Cent OS 6.4 . I used the command service httpd start for starting the server.

Comment: Did you added LoadModule php5_module ... directive before calling AddHandler?

Comment: This looks unrelated to Tomcat at all. What version of httpd are you running? Can you post the first 10 lines of `httpd.conf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use Apache HTTP server configuration file with Tomcat.
Tomcat has it's own config files in `TOMCAT-HOME/conf/` directory.

If you're actually talking about Apache HTTP, not Tomcat, you may get this error if there's no mime_module. Run `httpd -M` command to check if mime_module present or not.